# How to add index to a mysql database to improve performance?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a project that synchronizes contents on multiple clusters. I want to use two programs to do this task. One program periodically updates the existence status of contents on each cluster, The other program do the content copy when one content is not on all clusters.

The database tables are designed in following way.

```
table contents -- stores content information.
+----+----------+
| id |  name    |
+----+----------+
|  1 | content_1|
|  2 | content_2|
|  3 | content_3|
+----+----------+

table clusters -- stores cluster information
+----+----------+
| id |  name    |
+----+----------+
|  1 | cluster_1|
|  2 | cluster_2|
+----+----------+

table content_cluster -- each record indicates that one content is on one cluster
+----------+----------+-------------------+
|content_id|cluster_id|   last_update_date|
+----------+----------+-------------------+
|        1 |        1 |2020-10-01T11:30:00|
|        2 |        2 |2020-10-01T11:30:00|
|        3 |        1 |2020-10-01T10:30:00|
|        3 |        2 |2020-10-01T10:30:00|
+----------+----------+-------------------+
```

The first program updates these tables periodically (a little part may changed, most of the table stay the same). The second program iteratively gets one content record which is not on all clusters. The select query is something as follow.

```
SELECT content_id
FROM content_cluster
GROUP BY content_id
HAVING COUNT(cluster_id) < <cluster_number>
LIMIT 1;
```

It seems not so effective as I have to group the table on my each query.
As I am not familiar with database, I'm wondering if it is a good way to design the database. Do I have to add some indices? How should I write select query to make it effective?

Comment: Seems like a good way . For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Are you encountering poor performance? There's nothing in what you've described that suggests there should be a problem.

Comment: Thanks all. I haven't encountered any problem yet. It's still in designing phase. As I just start learning SQL, I was worried about the performance.